# Dont see Test tab in TWA for team foundation server express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am looking in TWS and I see the Home, code, work, and Build tabs. However I dont see the test tab that should br right next to the buld tab. I want to have web-based testcase management. 
How do I get it to show up?

I just downloaded team foundation server 2013 express

Answer (score 1):

The access level for your user or group needs to be set to full access. The default is limited. You can change the access level via the Control Panel --> user settings.

---

Form MSDN:

[Change access levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8bf4a761-7938-417e-a86a-704ae211cc5d)

**1.From the TFS home page (for example, myserver:8080/tfs), go to the server administration page.**

[image: server administration page]

**2. - Go to the administration page Select the level and then add the user or group.**
[image: Control Panel]

**Add the user or group
If you don’t see the Access levels tab, you aren't a TFS administrator and don’t have permission. [Here’s how to get permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb552341).**

Comment: i dont see user settings in my control panel

Comment: that gear is logo is not there and I added myself as administrator on the server. My best guess is that the licensing for tfs express doesn't allow this.

Comment: To use TWA testing you need full access which is one of these MSDN subscriptions: Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN, Visual Studio Premium with MSDN, or Visual Studio Test Professional with MSDN.